# How to run a shell script with a for loop which contains an array of arguments, each command should be run in a new terminal window in ubuntu

Tags: python, bash, shell, ubuntu, arguments

Here is my shell script code.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a my_array;
my_array=("arg1" "arg2" "arg3" "arg4" "arg5");

for i in "${my_array[@]}"; do
    gnome-terminal -x;
    cd /home/XXX/Documents/testing ;
    conda activate env1;
    python3 Parallel.py "$i" &
done
```

I am trying to run my programme Parallel.py which is located in the testing folder, each time with a different argument. A new terminal window should pop up each time and run the new command. For example the first terminal window should run:

```
cd /home/XXX/Documents/testing
conda activate env1
python3 Parallel.py arg1
```

then the next one should go

```
cd /home/XXX/Documents/testing
conda activate env1
python3 Parallel.py arg2
```

but all the windows should remain open and run the commands in parallel. right now what im getting is one window is running all the commands.

Comment: there is no `cd` in your `for` loop.

Comment: sorry i fixed it, it still doesnt work as intended.

Comment: That wasn't the solution though just wanted to make sure it's there :)

Comment: I would rather run `gnome-terminal -- script_which_runs_python_code.sh "$i" &`